# Importing a Python module in a package returns a different module from the same package

Tags: python, import

When I run an import in my development environment, I seem to get the wrong module.

How do I make sense of this?

```
$ python -c "import breathe.renderer.rst.doxygen.compound as com; print com"
<module 'breathe.parser.doxygen.compound' from 'breathe/parser/doxygen/compound.pyc'>
```

The layout of the breathe directory is:

```
breathe                                                                          
├── directives.py
├── finder
│   ├── doxygen
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── compound.py
│   │   ├── index.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── nodes.py
├── parser
│   ├── doxygen
│   │   ├── compound.py
│   │   ├── compoundsuper.py
│   │   ├── index.py
│   │   ├── indexsuper.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── process.py
├── renderer
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── rst
│       ├── doxygen
│       │   ├── base.py
│       │   ├── compound.py
│       │   ├── domain.py
│       │   ├── filter.py
│       │   ├── index.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── target.py
│       ├── __init__.py
└── transforms.py
```

Comment: check whether `__init__.py` in folders `breathe,renderer,rst and doxygen` is blank.

Comment: Do you have anything that might confuse it like symlinks or code that messes with `sys.modules`?

Comment: @aquavitae I don't have any symlinks or sys.modules code

Comment: @suhail I definitely have code in my __init__.py files. Is that unadvisable for some reason? I've never come across this conflict before. Should all __init__.py files be blank?

Comment: @MichaelJones There is nothing wrong with having code in `__init__.py`, but it could affect the import process.  I'll explain fully in an answer because its easier to format code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `breathe/renderer/rst/__init__.py` file.  I suspect that you have something like

```
from breathe.parser import doxygen
```

What happens is that when a module is imported, the module's `__init__.py` is executed.  Then the next submodule is imported and it's `__init__.py` is run.
So, in the above situation, you'll get `breathe.renderer.rst` importing fine, but when running
`breathe.renderer.rst.__init__`, the `breathe.parser.doxygen` module is bound to the local name `doxygen` overriding the `doxygen` submodule.  So you should see something like this:

```
>>> from breathe.renderer import rst
>>> print(rst.doxygen)
<module 'breathe.parser.doxygen' from 'breathe/parser/doxygen/__init__.pyc'>
```

Possible solutions:

1. Use absolute imports in `__init__.py`
2. Keep as much code as possible out of `__init__.py`
3. Use `import` inside the functions it's needed rather than globally.  (This can also resolve circular import problems)

Note that there is nothing that prohibits code in `__init__.py`, and several modules in the stdlib do it too.  However, because of exactly this sort of issue it is generally considered a good idea to avoid doing it too much.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This makes a lot of sense. I'll lean away from code in the `__init__.py` files for now.